# Unable to load Aggregate using Repository.load() for Integer AggregateIdentifier

Tags: repository, aggregate, cqrs, axon

I've been trying in vain to load an aggregate using the load method of the repository class. I know that the load() method requires a string argument but my aggregate identifier is integer.
I have tried to convert to string, yet I'm not able to load the aggregate. I keep getting null. 
My code is shown below

```
    @Autowired
private Repository<Product> repository;

@CommandHandler
public Order(CreateOrderCommand cmd){
    try{
        //This line throws an error
        Product product = (Product) repository.load(Integer.toString(cmd.getProductId()));
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Oops! Error Occured: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    apply(
            new OrderCreatedEvent(
                    cmd.getOrderId(), cmd.getPrice(), cmd.getNumber(), cmd.getProductId()
            )
    );
}
```

I'm providing an more updates:
I simply want to update the products stock, when a new order is placed. So what I did was that in the CommandHandler for creating a new Order, I simply find the Product aggregate and call it's UpdateStock method, which is a command handler.
Is there something I really don't understand?

These are the files below:
The Product aggregate:

```
@Aggregate
public class Product {
    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;
    private Double price;
    private Integer stock;
    private String description;

    public Product() {
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public Product(AddProductCommand cmd){
        apply( new ProductAddedEvent(
                cmd.getId(),
                cmd.getPrice(),
                cmd.getStock(),
                cmd.getDescription()
                )
        );
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void updateStock (UpdateStockCommand cmd){
        if(this.stock >= cmd.getStock()){
            apply(new StockUpdatedEvent(cmd.getId(), cmd.getStock()));
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Out of Stock!");
        }
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(StockUpdatedEvent evt){
        id = evt.getId();
        stock = stock - evt.getStock();
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(ProductAddedEvent evt){
        id = evt.getId();
        price = evt.getPrice();
        stock = evt.getStock();
        description = evt.getDescription();
    }
}
```

The Order aggregate:

```
@Aggregate
public class Order {
    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String  orderId;
    private Double price;
    private Integer number;
    private String productId;

    //Repository provides an abstraction for storage of Aggregates
    @Autowired
    private Repository<Product> repository;

    @CommandHandler
    public Order(CreateOrderCommand cmd){
        try{
            //This line throws an error
            Product product = (Product) repository.load(cmd.getProductId());

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Oops! Error Occured: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        apply(
                new OrderCreatedEvent(
                        cmd.getOrderId(), cmd.getPrice(), cmd.getNumber(), cmd.getProductId()
                )
        );
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(OrderCreatedEvent evt){
        orderId = evt.getOrderId();
        price = evt.getPrice();
        number = evt.getNumber();
        productId = evt.getProductId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have noticed, Axon will enforce a `String` for the aggregate identifier. This doesn't mean you need to provide a `String` directly. It'll work perfectly fine as long as you have a sensible `toString()` method implemented. Hence, using `Integer` as the aggregate identifier will result in the `toString()` result of that field to be used as the aggregate identifier.

Having said that, I'm surprised you are unable to load an aggregate based on this.
Maybe we need to do some follow up based on that, but firstly I want to comment on the snippet you're sharing.

It seems like you have a constructor command handler on the `Order` class. Moreover, that signals to me that the `Order` class is an aggregate.
I'd like to state that by **no means** would I ever recommend to load in an Aggregate from within another Aggregate.

Doing so ties in the lock on the `Order` aggregate with the `Product` aggregate, thus blocking a larger portion of your system than the sender of `CreateOrderCommand` would ever expect. 
Communication between aggregate should be kept asynchronous at all times, through means of event messages.
That thus requires a dedicated Event Handling Component which does the coordination between both instances based on the published event.

I'd thus strongly suggest a rewrite of your logic on the matter.
When it comes to loading in an aggregate, I'd be hard pressed to give you a reasoning right now. 
Hence, let me ask a couple of follow up questions.
I'd suggest to update your original request with the responses by the way; to maintain a nice thread of continuity.

Which version of Axon are you using any way?
Are you using any interesting configurations around the `Product` aggregate?
Are you pairing your application with Axon Server? If so, standard or enterprise, and which version?
Do you use the Configuration API directly or the `axon-spring-boot-starter`?

---

**Update**

Thanks for updating your question Kindson, let me update my answer too.

Firstly, as I already stated previously, I would **never** load in an Aggregate from within another Aggregate. Both your `Order` class and `Product` class are Aggregates and the snippets make overly clear that you are consolidating the "product `Repository`" from within the `Order` aggregate.

This approach does not only prolong locks on your aggregates, thus imposing strains on your users, but following this approach might event incur deadlocks. As a rule of thumb, *always* follow an asynchronous approach to communicating between aggregate instances. Thus a component reacting on an aggregate's events and dispatching commands to another. This can be done in a regular Event Handling Component, or a Saga for example.

Apart from the above, I have tested locally whether I could use an `Integer` as an Aggregate Identifier. Thus, as the `@AggregateIdentifier` annotated field in the aggregate *and* as the `@TargetAggregateIdentifier` annotated field on your command message. On top of that, I tried this out by having the framework call the `Repository#load(String)` operation (thus just dispatching a command on the `CommandGateway`/`CommandBus`) **and** by calling it directly as you did.

Sadly, this works out fine for me. Thus, as another follow up, I'd suggest to share the actual exception you are getting when you are performing the `Repository#load(String)` operation.

Comment: I use AxonServer 4.3 standard with axon-spring-boot-starter. No other configuration files.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please take note on the suggestion to **never** load an aggregate from within another aggregate.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven! This is quite clear. However, now I'm loading the aggregate through a @Component annotated class (OrderProjector). I already created the repository interface which extends the org.axonframework.modelling.command.Repository (this is in the query/apk.kt file). Surprisingly, I get an error that  says "Parameter 2 of constructor in com.example.ecom.query.OrderProjector required a bean of type 'com.example.ecom.query.ProductRepository' that could not be found'. Could you take a look. The repository for this is https://github.com/KindsonTheGenius/Ecomm

Comment: Guessing that issue arises through because of an incorrect Spring wiring order. The issue has already been marked here: https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/1123
The priority for this bug is not to high, as you can easily work around it by just publishing the command directly to the command model. I'd thus suggest to take that route instead of using the `Repository` yourself to search for the right `Order` aggregate.